# Understanding refs in rust when struct and it's member has different lifetime

Tags: reference, rust, lifetime, ownership, borrow-checker

I was playing around with the `lifetime` complexity in rust and I ended up writing the following code:

```
trait Boss<'a, 'c> {
  fn work(&self, &'a i32) -> &'c i32;
}

struct Human<'c> {
  i:&'c i32 
}

impl<'a, 'b, 'c> Boss<'a, 'c>  for &'b Human <'c> {
  fn work(&self, v:&'a i32) -> &'c i32 {
    &self.i
  }
}


fn main () {
  let h = Human {i:&1};
}
```

This code compiles, but I am not sure why. As i understand it, the `&Human` has lifetime of `'b`, whereas the reference member `i` of `struct Human` has `'c`. Why isn't the  compiler complaining that `'b` can outlive `'c` ?

Answer (score 0):

`h : Human<'static>`, and `'static` references meet any output lifetime requirement.

Try writing some code where `h.i` references a variable with shorter lifetime than h.

```
fn main () {
    let mut h = Human {i:&1};
    {
        let x : i32 = 3;
        h.i = &x;
    }
    let r = (&h).work(&3);
}

error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
  --> a.rs:21:5
   |
20 |         h.i = &x;
   |                - borrow occurs here
21 |     }
   |     ^ `x` dropped here while still borrowed
22 |     let r = (&h).work(&3);
23 | }
   | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```